# Permissions error in WordPress setup with Mariadb + NGINX and custom php-fpm Dockerfile

Tags: wordpress, docker, dockerfile, devops

I'm trying to configure a WordPress installation based on docker-compose and with official docker images and a custom Dockerfile based image for the php-fpm part.

The docker-compose is like follows:

```yaml
docker-compose.yml:
-------------------
  # MariaDB - MySQL Database
  mariadb:
    container_name: mariadb
    image: linuxserver/mariadb:latest
    restart: always
    security_opt:
      - no-new-privileges:true
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    secrets:
      - mysql_root_password
    volumes:
      - /home/docker/mariadb/data:/config
      - /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
    healthcheck:
      test: mysqladmin ping -h localhost -p$$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD && test '0' -eq $$(ps aux | awk '{print $$11}' | grep -c -e '^mysql$$')
    environment:
      - PUID=1000
      - PGID=998
      - TZ=Europe/Madrid
      - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=no
      - FILE__MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=/run/secrets/mysql_root_password
      - MYSQL_USER=wordpress
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=wordpress
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=wordpress
    secrets:
      - mysql_root_password


  # Nginx - Web Server
  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    image: nginx:1.18
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - php7
    healthcheck:
      test: pidof nginx
    networks:
      - t2_proxy
    volumes:
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      - /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro
      - /var/log/nginx:/var/log/nginx
      - /home/docker/nginx:/etc/nginx
      - /home/docker/shared/.htpasswd:/shared/.htpasswd
      - /home/docker/sites/wordpress/html:/var/www/html/wordpress
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      ## HTTP Routers (WordPress) Auth
      - "traefik.http.routers.nginx-wordpress-auth-rtr.entrypoints=https"
      - "traefik.http.routers.nginx-wordpress-auth-rtr.rule=Host(`example.com`) && Path(`/wp-login.php`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.nginx-wordpress-rtr.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.nginx-wordpress-auth-rtr.priority=100"
      ## HTTP Routers (WordPress) Bypass
      - "traefik.http.routers.nginx-wordpress-rtr.entrypoints=https"
      - "traefik.http.routers.nginx-wordpress-rtr.rule=Host(`example.com`) || Host(`www.example.com`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.nginx-wordpress-rtr.priority=99"
      # Redirect wordpress non-www to www middleware
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.wordpress-redirect.redirectregex.regex=^https?://www.example.com/(.*)"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.wordpress-redirect.redirectregex.replacement=https://example.com/$${1}"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.wordpress-redirect.redirectregex.permanent=true"
      ## Middlewares
      - "traefik.http.routers.nginx-wordpress-rtr.middlewares=wordpress-redirect,chain-no-auth-wp@file"
      - "traefik.http.routers.nginx-wordpress-auth-rtr.middlewares=wordpress-redirect,chain-authelia@file"


  # PHP - Hypertext Preprocessor
  php7:
    container_name: php7
    image: php:7.4-fpm-custom
    build:
      context: /home/docker/custom/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-php7
    restart: unless-stopped
    healthcheck:
      test: pidof php-fpm
    user: 1000:998 # allows upgrading WP and plugins
    networks:
      - t2_proxy
    volumes:
      - /home/docker/sites/wordpress/html:/var/www/html/wordpress
      - /home/docker/php/php7:/usr/local/etc/php
```

The Dockerfile used in the 'php7' container is based on official Wordpress php-fpm image:

Dockerfile-php7:

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm

# persistent dependencies
RUN set -eux; \
  apt-get update; \
  apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
# Ghostscript is required for rendering PDF previews
    ghostscript \
  ; \
  rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# install the PHP extensions we need (https://make.wordpress.org/hosting/handbook/handbook/server-environment/#php-extensions)
RUN set -ex; \
  \
  savedAptMark="$(apt-mark showmanual)"; \
  \
  apt-get update; \
  apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libjpeg-dev \
    libmagickwand-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libwebp-dev \
    libzip-dev \
  ; \
  \
  docker-php-ext-configure gd \
    --with-freetype \
    --with-jpeg \
    --with-webp \
  ; \
  docker-php-ext-install -j "$(nproc)" \
    bcmath \
    exif \
    gd \
    mysqli \
    zip \
  ; \
# https://pecl.php.net/package/imagick
  pecl install imagick-3.5.0; \
  docker-php-ext-enable imagick; \
  rm -r /tmp/pear; \
  \
# https://pecl.php.net/package/redis
    pecl install redis; \
    docker-php-ext-enable redis; \
    rm -r /tmp/pear; \
    \
# reset apt-mark's "manual" list so that "purge --auto-remove" will remove all build dependencies
  apt-mark auto '.*' > /dev/null; \
  apt-mark manual $savedAptMark; \
  ldd "$(php -r 'echo ini_get("extension_dir");')"/*.so \
    | awk '/=>/ { print $3 }' \
    | sort -u \
    | xargs -r dpkg-query -S \
    | cut -d: -f1 \
    | sort -u \
    | xargs -rt apt-mark manual; \
  \
  apt-get purge -y --auto-remove -o APT::AutoRemove::RecommendsImportant=false; \
  rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# set recommended PHP.ini settings
# see https://secure.php.net/manual/en/opcache.installation.php
RUN set -eux; \
  docker-php-ext-enable opcache; \
  { \
    echo 'opcache.memory_consumption=128'; \
    echo 'opcache.interned_strings_buffer=8'; \
    echo 'opcache.max_accelerated_files=4000'; \
    echo 'opcache.revalidate_freq=2'; \
    echo 'opcache.fast_shutdown=1'; \
  } > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/opcache-recommended.ini
# https://wordpress.org/support/article/editing-wp-config-php/#configure-error-logging
RUN { \
# https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php
# https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/issues/420#issuecomment-517839670
    echo 'error_reporting = E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_CORE_ERROR | E_CORE_WARNING | E_COMPILE_ERROR | E_COMPILE_WARNING | E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR'; \
    echo 'display_errors = Off'; \
    echo 'display_startup_errors = Off'; \
    echo 'log_errors = On'; \
    echo 'error_log = /dev/stderr'; \
    echo 'log_errors_max_len = 1024'; \
    echo 'ignore_repeated_errors = On'; \
    echo 'ignore_repeated_source = Off'; \
    echo 'html_errors = Off'; \
  } > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/error-logging.ini
```

I ensure that all Wordpress files are in the correct folder:

```sh
root@ubuntu:/home/docker# ls -l sites/wordpress/html/
total 220
-rw-r-----  1 1000 998   405 Feb  6  2020 index.php
-rw-r-----  1 1000 998 19915 Jan  1  2021 license.txt
-rw-r-----  1 1000 998  7346 Jul  6 12:23 readme.html
-rw-r-----  1 1000 998  7165 Jan 21  2021 wp-activate.php
drwxr-x---  9 1000 998  4096 Sep  9 02:20 wp-admin
-rw-r-----  1 1000 998   351 Feb  6  2020 wp-blog-header.php
-rw-r-----  1 1000 998  2328 Feb 17  2021 wp-comments-post.php
-rw-r-----  1 1000 998  3004 May 21 10:40 wp-config-sample.php
-rw-r--r--  1 1000 998  3153 Oct  5 05:47 wp-config.php
drwxr-x---  4 1000 998  4096 Sep  9 02:20 wp-content
-rw-r-----  1 1000 998  3939 Jul 30  2020 wp-cron.php
drwxr-x--- 25 1000 998 16384 Sep  9 02:20 wp-includes
-rw-r-----  1 1000 998  2496 Feb  6  2020 wp-links-opml.php
-rw-r-----  1 1000 998  3900 May 15 17:38 wp-load.php
-rw-r-----  1 1000 998 45463 Apr  6 18:39 wp-login.php
-rw-r-----  1 1000 998  8509 Apr 14  2020 wp-mail.php
-rw-r-----  1 1000 998 22297 Jun  1 23:09 wp-settings.php
-rw-r-----  1 1000 998 31693 May  7 20:16 wp-signup.php
-rw-r-----  1 1000 998  4747 Oct  8  2020 wp-trackback.php
-rw-r-----  1 1000 998  3236 Jun  8  2020 xmlrpc.php
```

And the wp-config is pointing to the correct database:

```php
wp-config.php
-------------

// ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define( 'DB_NAME', 'wordpress' );

/** MySQL database username */
define( 'DB_USER', 'wordpress' );

/** MySQL database password */
define( 'DB_PASSWORD', 'wordpress' );

/** MySQL hostname */
define( 'DB_HOST', 'mariadb' );

/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define( 'DB_CHARSET', 'utf8' );

/** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define( 'DB_COLLATE', '' );

/** Filesystem access **/
define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');
```

With this setup, when I reach https://example.com I got a "File not found" error.

[image: file not found error]

If I changed the ownership of the Wordpress files folder (/home/docker/sites/wordpress/html/) to 'docker' user I'm able to see the Wordpress app running, but and "Error establishing a database connection"

[image: wordpress error]

### docker ps -a:

[image: docker ps -a]

### docker logs mariadb:

```sh
root@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-intel-ams3-01:/home/docker# docker logs mariadb
[s6-init] making user provided files available at /var/run/s6/etc...exited 0.
[s6-init] ensuring user provided files have correct perms...exited 0.
[fix-attrs.d] applying ownership & permissions fixes...
[fix-attrs.d] done.
[cont-init.d] executing container initialization scripts...
[cont-init.d] 01-envfile: executing... 
[env-init] MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD set from FILE__MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
[cont-init.d] 01-envfile: exited 0.
[cont-init.d] 10-adduser: executing... 

-------------------------------------
          _         ()
         | |  ___   _    __
         | | / __| | |  /  \ 
         | | \__ \ | | | () |
         |_| |___/ |_|  \__/


Brought to you by linuxserver.io
-------------------------------------

To support LSIO projects visit:
https://www.linuxserver.io/donate/
-------------------------------------
GID/UID
-------------------------------------

User uid:    1000
User gid:    998
-------------------------------------

[cont-init.d] 10-adduser: exited 0.
[cont-init.d] 30-config: executing... 
[cont-init.d] 30-config: exited 0.
[cont-init.d] 40-initialise-db: executing... 
Setting Up Initial Databases
Installing MariaDB/MySQL system tables in '/config/databases' ...
2021-10-05  7:53:00 1 [Warning] Failed to load slave replication state from table mysql.gtid_slave_pos: 1017: Can't find file: './mysql/' (errno: 2 "No such file or directory")
OK

To start mysqld at boot time you have to copy
support-files/mysql.server to the right place for your system


PLEASE REMEMBER TO SET A PASSWORD FOR THE MariaDB root USER !
To do so, start the server, then issue the following command:

'/usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation'

which will also give you the option of removing the test
databases and anonymous user created by default.  This is
strongly recommended for production servers.

See the MariaDB Knowledgebase at https://mariadb.com/kb or the
MySQL manual for more instructions.

You can start the MariaDB daemon with:
cd '/usr' ; /usr/bin/mysqld_safe --datadir='/config/databases'

You can test the MariaDB daemon with mysql-test-run.pl
cd '/usr/mysql-test' ; perl mysql-test-run.pl

Please report any problems at https://mariadb.org/jira

The latest information about MariaDB is available at https://mariadb.org/.
You can find additional information about the MySQL part at:
https://dev.mysql.com
Consider joining MariaDB's strong and vibrant community:
https://mariadb.org/get-involved/

2021-10-05  7:53:01 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 10.5.12-MariaDB-log) starting as process 306 ...
2021-10-05  7:53:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2021-10-05  7:53:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2021-10-05  7:53:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2021-10-05  7:53:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using crc32 + pclmulqdq instructions
2021-10-05  7:53:02 0 [Note] mysqld: O_TMPFILE is not supported on /var/tmp (disabling future attempts)
2021-10-05  7:53:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2021-10-05  7:53:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 268435456, chunk size = 134217728
2021-10-05  7:53:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2021-10-05  7:53:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segments are active.
2021-10-05  7:53:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2021-10-05  7:53:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2021-10-05  7:53:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2021-10-05  7:53:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.5.12 started; log sequence number 45094; transaction id 20
2021-10-05  7:53:02 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2021-10-05  7:53:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /config/databases/ib_buffer_pool
2021-10-05  7:53:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 211005  7:53:02
2021-10-05  7:53:02 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2021-10-05  7:53:02 0 [Note] Reading of all Master_info entries succeeded
2021-10-05  7:53:02 0 [Note] Added new Master_info '' to hash table
2021-10-05  7:53:02 0 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '10.5.12-MariaDB-log'  socket: '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MariaDB Server
2021-10-05  7:53:03 0 [Note] mysqld (initiated by: root[root] @ localhost []): Normal shutdown
2021-10-05  7:53:03 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
2021-10-05  7:53:03 0 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2021-10-05  7:53:03 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2021-10-05  7:53:03 0 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) to /config/databases/ib_buffer_pool
2021-10-05  7:53:03 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) dump completed at 211005  7:53:03
2021-10-05  7:53:04 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2021-10-05  7:53:04 0 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 45106; transaction id 23
2021-10-05  7:53:04 0 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete

Database Setup Completed
[cont-init.d] 40-initialise-db: exited 0.
[cont-init.d] 90-custom-folders: executing... 
[cont-init.d] 90-custom-folders: exited 0.
[cont-init.d] 99-custom-files: executing... 
[custom-init] no custom files found exiting...
[cont-init.d] 99-custom-files: exited 0.
[cont-init.d] done.
[services.d] starting services
[services.d] done.
211005 07:53:05 mysqld_safe Logging to '/config/databases/1e14f4ec3953.err'.
211005 07:53:05 mysqld_safe Starting mariadbd daemon with databases from /config/databases
```

### docker logs php7:

```sh
[05-Oct-2021 05:52:57] NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_mysql' (tried: /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/pdo_mysql (/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/pdo_mysql: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/pdo_mysql.so (/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/pdo_mysql.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
[05-Oct-2021 05:52:57] NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mcrypt' (tried: /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/mcrypt (/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/mcrypt: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/mcrypt.so (/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/mcrypt.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
[05-Oct-2021 05:52:57] NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pspell' (tried: /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/pspell (/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/pspell: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/pspell.so (/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/pspell.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
[05-Oct-2021 05:52:57] NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'sockets' (tried: /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/sockets (/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/sockets: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/sockets.so (/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/sockets.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
[05-Oct-2021 05:52:57] NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'ssh2' (tried: /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/ssh2 (/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/ssh2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/ssh2.so (/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/ssh2.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
[05-Oct-2021 05:52:58] NOTICE: [pool www] 'user' directive is ignored when FPM is not running as root
[05-Oct-2021 05:52:58] NOTICE: [pool www] 'user' directive is ignored when FPM is not running as root
[05-Oct-2021 05:52:58] NOTICE: [pool www] 'group' directive is ignored when FPM is not running as root
[05-Oct-2021 05:52:58] NOTICE: [pool www] 'group' directive is ignored when FPM is not running as root
[05-Oct-2021 05:52:58] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 1
[05-Oct-2021 05:52:58] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
192.168.90.10 -  05/Oct/2021:05:57:30 +0000 "GET /index.php" 404
192.168.90.10 -  05/Oct/2021:05:57:32 +0000 "GET /index.php" 404
192.168.90.10 -  05/Oct/2021:05:59:02 +0000 "GET /index.php" 404
192.168.90.10 -  05/Oct/2021:06:00:00 +0000 "GET /index.php" 404
192.168.90.10 -  05/Oct/2021:06:23:19 +0000 "GET /index.php" 500
192.168.90.10 -  05/Oct/2021:06:23:20 +0000 "GET /index.php" 500
192.168.90.10 -  05/Oct/2021:06:23:21 +0000 "GET /index.php" 500
192.168.90.10 -  05/Oct/2021:06:25:23 +0000 "GET /index.php" 500
192.168.90.10 -  05/Oct/2021:06:25:24 +0000 "GET /index.php" 500
192.168.90.10 -  05/Oct/2021:06:25:24 +0000 "GET /index.php" 500
192.168.90.10 -  05/Oct/2021:06:26:39 +0000 "GET /index.php" 500
192.168.90.10 -  05/Oct/2021:06:26:40 +0000 "GET /index.php" 500
192.168.90.10 -  05/Oct/2021:06:27:22 +0000 "GET /index.php" 500
192.168.90.10 -  05/Oct/2021:06:29:30 +0000 "GET /index.php" 500
192.168.90.10 -  05/Oct/2021:06:29:31 +0000 "GET /index.php" 500
192.168.90.10 -  05/Oct/2021:06:29:31 +0000 "GET /index.php" 500
192.168.90.10 -  05/Oct/2021:06:29:31 +0000 "GET /index.php" 500
192.168.90.10 -  05/Oct/2021:06:29:32 +0000 "GET /index.php" 500
192.168.90.10 -  05/Oct/2021:06:29:32 +0000 "GET /index.php" 500
192.168.90.10 -  05/Oct/2021:06:29:32 +0000 "GET /index.php" 500
192.168.90.10 -  05/Oct/2021:06:29:41 +0000 "GET /wp-admin/index.php" 500
192.168.90.10 -  05/Oct/2021:06:29:42 +0000 "GET /wp-admin/index.php" 500
192.168.90.10 -  05/Oct/2021:06:29:43 +0000 "GET /wp-admin/index.php" 500
192.168.90.10 -  05/Oct/2021:06:31:36 +0000 "GET /wp-admin/index.php" 500
```

I think my problem is something with the PUID/PGID and users, but I can't get it work. Hope someone could point me in the right direction.

Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 2):

It's because of the complicated and so strict that your file permission configured. I think that you are trying to config your php-fpm to use user 1000 and group 998. But it is a wrong way because php-fpm also need to access to `/usr/local/lib/php/*` to load php extensions. Php-fpm has it owned mechanism to to switch to another user to serve client request while using root (or other power user to load PHP/system configurations). Because you are not using root to start php-fpm so it does not have permission to switch to another user, so you see the logs:

```
[05-Oct-2021 05:52:58] NOTICE: [pool www] 'user' directive is ignored when FPM is not running as root
[05-Oct-2021 05:52:58] NOTICE: [pool www] 'user' directive is ignored when FPM is not running as root
[05-Oct-2021 05:52:58] NOTICE: [pool www] 'group' directive is ignored when FPM is not running as root
[05-Oct-2021 05:52:58] NOTICE: [pool www] 'group' directive is ignored when FPM is not running as root
```

There are many ways to resolve your problems. If you still expect to use too strict the file permission like that, you will have to keep running php-fpm as root but on the php-fpm configuration (usually at `etc/php-fpm.d/*.conf`), you set `user` to 1000 and `group` to 998, so php-fpm will use that user and group to serve your client request and that user will be able to read your current source code files. However, I think you will have to make sure that user 1000 and 998 are existed in the image.

Secondly, I think your permission model is too strict and not necessary. I will grant +r for public to the source code files and start php-fpm as root (by default it will use www user to serve clients).